# How to display data in MainPanel based on user selection in Shiny R?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

My dataframe looks like below, and I would like to build `ShinyApp` such that when user selects System from SidebarPanel only info. related to selected system gets  displayed in `mainpanel`. Currently, below app displays entire datatable in mainpanel. I am  new to shiny and I not sure how to hide datatable in `mainpanel`.

Is there any functionality available in Shiny ?

Provide explanation with code

**DataFrame**

```
> df <- data.frame("Users" =c('A',"B","A",'C','B'), "Date" = c('17 Mar 2019','15 Mar 2019','11 Mar 2019','20 Apr 2019',"21 Apr 2019"), "Systems" = c("Sys1", "Sys1","Sys2","Sys3","Sys4"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df
  Users        Date Systems
1     A 17 Mar 2019    Sys1
2     B 15 Mar 2019    Sys1
3     A 11 Mar 2019    Sys2
4     C 20 Apr 2019    Sys3
5     B 21 Apr 2019    Sys4
```

**App so far..**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
ui <- basicPage(
  h2("Different Systems"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('slct',"Select System",choices = df$Systems)
  ),
  mainPanel(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)
)
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  #df$system<-rownames(df$Systems)
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    df %>%
      filter(stringr::str_detect(Systems, as.character(input$slct)))

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1:

You ca use `req()` to ensure that `input$slct` must be available for the table to be displayed.

You only need to change your server code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    #df$system<-rownames(df$Systems)
    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
        req(input$slct) # add this line
        df %>%
            filter(stringr::str_detect(Systems, as.character(input$slct)))

    })

}
```

### Option 2:

You can use `validate()` and `need` make requirements and suggest user input.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    #df$system<-rownames(df$Systems)
    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
        validate(need(input$slct,"Please Select System")) # add this line
        df %>%
            filter(stringr::str_detect(Systems, as.character(input$slct)))

    })

}
```

Read those two articles for more information:

1. https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html
2. https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html