# How to resetform after selection in ShinyR?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

This question is extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126285/how-to-display-data-in-mainpanel-based-on-user-selection-in-shiny-r). I would like to take this App to next step where after selecting "System", user should be able to click on Reset Form button,which will clear the selected "System" in the "Select System" and also clear the output that is displayed in `mainpanel`. I am able to completely reset the selected option. However, I cannot clear datatable.

Please provide explanation with code.

**Code that clears the selected input...**

```
df <- data.frame("Users" =c('A',"B","A",'C','B'), "Date" = c('17 Mar 2019','15 Mar 2019','11 Mar 2019','20 Apr 2019',"21 Apr 2019"), "Systems" = c("Sys1", "Sys1","Sys2","Sys3","Sys4"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

resetForm<-function(session){
  updateSelectInput(session,"slct",selected = 'Null')
  }


ui <- basicPage(
  h2("Different Systems"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('slct',"Select System",choices = df$Systems),
      actionButton('clear',"Reset Form")
  ),
  mainPanel(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)
)
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  #df$system<-rownames(df$Systems)
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$slct) # add this line
    df %>%
      filter(stringr::str_detect(Systems, as.character(input$slct)))
  })
  observeEvent(input$clear,{
    req(input$slct)
    resetForm(session)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts in `selectInput`:

1. The text displayed on UI.
2. The value passed to server

Those two values can be the same or different depending on what is provided to `choices`.

By setting `updateSelectInput(session,"slct",selected = 'Null')`, it sets the selected value to `'Null'`, but `'Null'` is not provided in `choices`, so it will be displayed as blank in UI.

The result is that: you provide something not in the `choices` and `SelectInput` won't pass the value to the server. So `input$slct` remains unchanged.

**To confirm that , you can try:**

Add `print(input$slct)` after `resetForm(session)` in your server codes. And you should find that `resetForm()` can't reset `input$slct`.

### To ansewer your question:

1. Change your `resetForm()` function to:

You should use `""` since it's very special. It is counted as a choice but it won't be displayed in UI.

```
resetForm<-function(session){
    updateSelectInput(session,"slct",selected = "")
}
```

2. Modify `choices` in `selectInput`:

```
# Change choices to c("",df$Systems)
selectInput('slct',"Select System",choices = c("",df$Systems)),
```

### The following script should work:

```
df <- data.frame("Users" =c('A',"B","A",'C','B'), "Date" = c('17 Mar 2019','15 Mar 2019','11 Mar 2019','20 Apr 2019',"21 Apr 2019"), "Systems" = c("Sys1", "Sys1","Sys2","Sys3","Sys4"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

resetForm<-function(session){
    updateSelectInput(session,"slct",selected = '')
}


ui <- basicPage(
    h2("Different Systems"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput('slct',"Select System",choices = c("",df$Systems)),
            actionButton('clear',"Reset Form")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
    #df$system<-rownames(df$Systems)
    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
        req(input$slct) # add this line
        df %>%
            filter(stringr::str_detect(Systems, as.character(input$slct)))
    })
    observeEvent(input$clear,{
        req(input$slct)
        resetForm(session)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```